# Why Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor creates more thread than CorePoolSize & MaxPoolSize

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for thread management. I am calling my Welcome service class from WelcomeController class.Each request is creating new thread. like My Thread-1,My Thread-2,My Thread-3.......My Thread-300.
As per documentation , queue depth is Intger.MAX and CorePoolSize=2, all the request has to go to queue and only 2 thread should work. But I am seeing more threads.

Why thread count is > CorePoolSize ??

How to fix this issue ? What mistake I am doing ??

**spring-boot-starter-parent =  2.1.7.RELEASE**

```
@Bean(name = "My Thread Pool")
  public Executor myTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(2);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(3);
    pool.setKeepAliveSeconds(30);
    pool.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    pool.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    pool.setThreadNamePrefix("My Thread-");
    return pool;
  }

@Service
class Welcome {

    @Async("My Thread Pool")
    public void sayHello() {
     System.out.println(" Thread Name"+Thread.currentThread().getName());

    }

}
```

Comment: Each thread created will get a new number, it doesn't reuse threadnames. So it start with 2 threads, will grow, then shrink, create new threads but the counter will keep increasing. So the fact that you see `My-Thread-300` doesn't mean there are 300 threads. It means that there have been 300 threads created but there should not be more than 30 active. YOu should be able to see statistics. Also if you are using Spring Boot there is already a predefined taskexecutor for you so you don't need to create it.

Answer (score 4):

Every time a thread is created it gets the incremeted number postfix.

From docs of `allowCoreThreadTimeOut()` method:

> If false (default), core threads stay alive even when idle. If true,
> core threads use keepAliveTime to time out waiting for work.

The default timeout is configured with option `keepAliveSeconds` which is set in `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` to 60 seconds by default.

So, if you have `allowCoreThreadTimeOut()` enabled, then the threads will be terminated after timeout if they have no work within the thread keep alive time.

After this if you submit a task to your executor, the new thread will be created with the increased thread number postfix.

So, it does not mean at all that you have, for example, 300 threads within your executor if you can see the thread with `-300` postfix.